# Melt data frame with headers with the same name in Rstudio

Tags: r, dplyr

I hope someone can help with this problem!

I'm trying to melt this table, the issue is that my headers have similar names and when imported into Rstudio the header are modified by Rstudio and it goes from NDUFS4 to NDUFS4.1, NDUFS4.2 etc

The data frame looks like that before melt

```
df <- read.csv("barplot-error-bars.csv")
df
         ID      NDUFS4     NDUFS4.1    NDUFS4.2     NDUFS4.3
1  AGlcSiE 0.003180784 0.0024272530 0.002375452 0.0023496160
2      Cer 0.013791754 0.0126248460 0.013400419 0.0119379920
3       CL 0.000486482 0.0003401490 0.000404080 0.0004320290
4       DG 0.026223988 0.0238132270 0.024463572 0.0257862250
5     DGDG 0.027734765 0.0284323830 0.027978220 0.0305652530
6      LPC 0.000052614 0.0000436625 0.000033694 0.0000339243
7     MGDG 0.153828915 0.1532680840 0.142490287 0.1636577930
8       PC 0.512484448 0.5241883360 0.543522684 0.5128264150
9       PE 0.014686845 0.0133621010 0.013992584 0.0159446760
```

And then I use melt :

```
dflong <- melt(df, id.vars=c("ID"))

     ID variable        value
1   AGlcSiE   NDUFS4 0.0031807840
2       Cer   NDUFS4 0.0137917540
3        CL   NDUFS4 0.0004864820
4        DG   NDUFS4 0.0262239880
...
19  AGlcSiE NDUFS4.1 0.0024272530
20      Cer NDUFS4.1 0.0126248460
21       CL NDUFS4.1 0.0003401490
22       DG NDUFS4.1 0.0238132270
...
38      Cer NDUFS4.2 0.0134004190
39       CL NDUFS4.2 0.0004040800
40       DG NDUFS4.2 0.0244635720
41     DGDG NDUFS4.2 0.0279782200
42      LPC NDUFS4.2 0.0000336940

etc etc
```

I'd like to get rid of the **.1**, **.2**, **.3**  after NDUFS4 that Rtsudio added when reading the csv.
I've tried renaming the colum headers :

```
names(df)[names(df) == "NDUFS.4.1"] <- "NDUFS.4"
```

It works but then the melt function doesn't really work, I end up with a 54row data frame which means something went wrong, I'm guessing because the columns have the same name, that would make sense.

So I've decided to create a new column to get rid of the .1, .2, .3 and to do so I use the mutate function :

```
dflong %>% mutate(genotype = case_when(
    startsWith(variable, "NDFUS4") ~ "NDUFS4",
    startsWith(variable, "NDUFS8") ~ "NDUFS8",
    startsWith(variable,"col0") ~"Col0" ))
```

but I get this error message :

```
> dflong %>% mutate(genotype = case_when(
+     startsWith(variable, "NDFUS.4") ~ "NDUFS-4",
+     startsWith(variable, "NDUFS.8") ~ "NDUFS-8",
+     startsWith(variable,"col0") ~"Col0" ))
Error: Problem with `mutate()` column `genotype`.
i `genotype = case_when(...)`.
x non-character object(s)
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
```

I've tried using as.character :

```
dfchar <- dflong
dfchar <- as.character(dflong$variable) 
sapply(dflong, class) 

dfchar %>% mutate(genotype = case_when(
    startsWith(variable, "NDFUS.4") ~ "NDUFS-4",
    startsWith(variable, "NDUFS.8") ~ "NDUFS-8",
    startsWith(variable,"col0") ~"Col0" ))
```

But doesn't work either :

```
> dfchar <- dflong
> dfchar <- as.character(dflong$variable) 
> dfchar %>% mutate(genotype = case_when(
+     startsWith(variable, "NDFUS.4") ~ "NDUFS-4",
+     startsWith(variable, "NDUFS.8") ~ "NDUFS-8",
+     startsWith(variable,"col0") ~"Col0" ))
Error in UseMethod("mutate") : 
  no applicable method for 'mutate' applied to an object of class "character"
```

It doesn't seems like a difficult thing to do but I'm out of idea and I haven't found a good solution online .. If anyone has an idea to get the melt function to work with header with the same name or a workaround I'm up for it !

Thank you for reading !
Cheers,
JB

Comment: Hi! What about removing whatever is after the point? `gsub("\\..*","",c("NDUFS4","NDUFS4.1","NDUFS4.2","NDUFS4.3"))`?

Comment: Well I did that but then the melt function doesn't work like it should ...

Comment: I think it’d be simpler if you did the renaming after.

Comment: Melt only takes the first NDUFS4 row and the first NDUFS8 row, ignoring the rest the rows

Comment: Yeah I think so but I'm stuck with the mutate function that I can't seems to figure out